# Error running bash script

Tags: bash, sh

Trying to run the following [bash script](https://gist.github.com/radianttap/43455d9b92433895e73c64c3d3690761) but get the below error message(s) - any ideas how to correct?

[image: Error Message]

Comment: Don't post images; include the text of your script and the error messages directly in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a wget program on Your mac. The fastest way to get it is via cURL.

> curl -O http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/wget-1.15.tar.gz

Extract cURL:

> tar -zxvf wget-1.15.tar.gz

open folder:

> cd wget-1.15/

And run installer

> ./configure

Comment: The fastest way to get `wget` installed is to install it through your platform's package manager. Besides, the command sequence you are giving here does *not* put `wget` into the command path, so it doesn't even solve the OP's problem.